# Passing primitive type to WCF RESTful service

Tags: wcf, json, rest, primitive-types

I've been banging my head against the wall for the past couple of hours, here's what we're trying to do: a method expects a primitive/simple type as the request body. Originally we tried with a boolean, but that didn't work so we tried with string and object. Same thing.

Here's the server-side code

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/foo/{foo_id}/bar", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.JSON)]
string G(string foo_id, string content);
```

And here's the request in Fiddler:

Header:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Content-Type: 'application/json',
Content-Length: 19
```

Body:

```
"hello_world"
```

We tried to wrap `"hello_world"` in a json object, like {"content":"hello_world"} but no luck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Forgot to mention the behavior: if I put a breakpoint in the method, it's not hit. Instead, I just get a 400 error coming back to Fiddler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me,  here's my code:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/foo/{foo_id}/bar", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string G(string foo_id, string content)
{
    return content + foo_id;
}
```

You didn't set the request format (a pain I know :))

Here's my Fiddler request:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:54287
Content-Length: 7
"Hello"
```

Comment: I thought the request format was picked up dynamically based on the content/type?

Comment: No, that's what HTTP should do, and one of numerous features WCF REST doesn't have.